# Firestore admin "listens" to all documents again on reboot

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

**TL;DR**
Every time my Fiestore admin server reboots my document listener is triggered for all documents even if I have already listened to the document and processed it. How do I get around this?
**End TL;DR**

I'm working on building a backend for my Firestore chat application. The basic idea is that whenever a users enters a chat message through a client app the backend server listens for new messages and processes them.

The problem I'm running into is that whenever I reboot my app server the listener is triggered for all of the existing already processed chats. So, it will respond to each chat even though it has already responded previously. I would like the app server to only respond to new chats that it hasn't already responded to.

One idea I have for a work around is to put a boolean flag on each chat document. When the backend processes the chat document it will set the flag. The listener will then only reply to chats that don't have the flag set.

Is this a sound approach or is there a better method? One concern I have is that every time I reboot my app server I will be charged heavily to re-query all of the previous chats. Another concern I have is that listening seems memory bound? If my app scales massively will I have to store all chat documents in memory? That doesn't seem like it will scale well...

```
    //Example listener that processes chats based on whether or not the "hasBeenRepliedTo" flag is set
    public void startFirestoreListener() {
        CollectionReference docRef = db.collection("chats");
        docRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirestoreException e) {
            if(e != null) {
                logger.error("There was an error listening to changes in the firestore chats collection. E: "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            else if(queryDocumentSnapshots != null && !queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                for(ChatDocument chatDoc : queryDocumentSnapshots.toObjects(ChatDocument.class)) {
                    if(!chatDoc.getHasBeenRepliedTo() {
                        //Do some processing
                        chatDoc.setHasBeenRepliedTo(true); //Set replied to flag
                   }
                   else {
                     //No-op, we've already replied to this chat
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, to avoid getting each document all the time, you will have to construct a query that yields only the documents that you know have been processed.

No, you are not charged to query documents.  You are charged only to read them, which will happen if your query yields documents.

Yes, you will have to be able to hold all the results of a query in memory.

Your problem will be much easier to solve if you use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to receive events for each new document in a collection.  You won't have to worry about any of the above things, and instead just worry about writing a [Firestore trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) that does what you want with each new document, and paying for those invocations.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Cloud functions are a much better option for my use case. That is the route I will go. I appreciate your activity answering Firebase questions. It is making the development experience a pleasure.